# Using viewer page to switch between two fragments - however it disappears after switching into a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager

I have a problem with my viewer page, so in this java file that I have which extends from Fragment has some code to do with view pager. Basically in my screen I want to let the user to swipe cross to the right and swipe across to the left. It works fine as it should be however I have other fragments too within the project I am working on so if I go to a different fragment and come back to this screen which lets me do this swipe feature, all for a sudden everything disappears from the screen. Any idea how to fix this issue ??

This is the java file;

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
   View v;
   ViewPager viewPager;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      final View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_main, container, false);

      viewPager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.accountswitching);
      AccountSwitching accountSwitching = new AccountSwitching(getFragmentManager());
      viewPager.setAdapter(accountSwitching);
```

This is the code I have inside the AccountSwitching  java class;

```
public class AccountSwitching extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public AccountSwitching(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    switch (i){
        case 0:
            return new FirstPage();
        case 1:
            return new SecondPage();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

}

So as you saw on the image I attached on this post, where it says hello, I have got an onclick which is in the FirstPage. java file

FirstPage. java file ;

```
public class FirstPage extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_screenmain_first, container, false);

    v.findViewById(R.id.first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ((FrameLayout)getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent)).removeAllViews();
            transaction.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, new ChangeScreen(), "ChangeScreen");
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

```
return v;
   }
}
```

This is a screen show of something from the viewer page is showing on the screen [Example of what I am seeing before switching between fragments](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pvp0a7b3aiz938/Screenshot_2015-04-12-11-56-43-1.png?dl=0)

This is what I see after switching between fragments [After switching between fragments](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xm9rqz7rryiuexy/Screenshot_2015-04-12-11-57-20-1.png?dl=0)

Please tell me if you want to see any other code, not sure which code to send here that's why I didn't share it on here.

Comment: have you tried calling the pager from the mainactivity

Comment: No I haven't, and how do I go about doing that ?

Comment: check out this tutorial  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/

Comment: My view pager working fine now, its the onclick I am getting error from. Please can you have a look at my log cat and help me with that

Comment: where is the logcat and onclick method

Comment: I have updated my post, where it says "FirstPage. java file ;" thats where my setOnClickListener is in. This is my log cat -  https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pdwbp3wx08j7et/logcat.txt?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75050/discussion-between-jomin-george94-and-hell).

Comment: Idk exactly coz I haven't tried your code but I think you are having problem with this piece of code     android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Comment: Try changing fragmenttransition to fragment manager

Comment: I have tried that but won't let me change it to Fragment Manager

Comment: Wt is the error its showing

Comment: I fixed it , it was the layout I was replacing with . THank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are creating a ViewPager inside a fragment.

In this case `getFragmentManager()` should be `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I have tried this and it works but after clicking on the hello, where I have got an onclick it breaks. Please look at my updated post. I have posted my log cat here too [https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pdwbp3wx08j7et/logcat.txt?dl=0]

Comment: It is a different problem: No view found for id 0x1020011 (android:id/tabcontent)

Comment: Well, hard to know for sure when I dont know what you are trying to accomplish. You could try using `android.R.id.content` instead, perhaps adding the fragment instead of replacing in FirstPage fragment.

Comment: do you mean it like this ?                                                           android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();                                               ((FrameLayout)getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent)).removeAllViews();                                                                                       transaction.add(android.R.id.content, new ChangeScreen());                              transaction.commit();

Comment: Remove this line `((FrameLayout)getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent)).removeAllView‌​s();` dont think it is needed if you add the fragment atop the layout. You might want to do `transaction.addToBackstack()` as well

Comment: So on the ChangeScreen() java file , inside the onclick I did this based on what you said;                                                                                                           android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(android.R.id.content, new OverviewFragment());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

Comment: 'Did not work' is not easy to debug - what errors are you getting? But, as you again reside inside fragment `getFragmentManager()` should be `getChildFragmentManager`. Though, as you seem to want to replace the content of the whole screen, it would seem more 'right' to let the activity add the new fragment e.g. something like `((YourActivity)getActivity()).replaceContent(new OverviewFragment)`, then do the transaction in the `replaceContent()` method. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: I am not actually sure how to do that, so on the onclick what should I write

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75052/discussion-between-jomin-george94-and-cyrixmorten).

Comment: This is the log cat I am getting - https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ok925rfaci77yu/Logcat%20-%20updated%20at%2014.04.txt?dl=0

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use `R.android.id.tabcontent` again for fragment ChangeScreen. If you, yourself define an id called tabcontent in your XML, it should be `R.id.tabcontent`