# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x1020011

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener

I have got this error in my project I am working on. I have got this java class called FirstActivity that extends from Fragment.

FirstActivity. java file;

```
public class FirstActivity extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);

    v.findViewById(R.id.firstaccountoverview).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ((FrameLayout)getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent)).removeAllViews();
            transaction.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, new ExampleFragment(), "");
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

I am new to this so I am not sure if I should give out more information, please do ask if you do need it :)

Comment: Post logcat and first activity java

Comment: This is the LogCat - https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ok925rfaci77yu/Logcat%20-%20updated%20at%2014.04.txt?dl=0

Comment: first activity java file is the one that I have posted in here

Comment: Are there any activities in your app?

Comment: Yeah there is but do you need those ? I mean there is a few activities I got

Comment: This is a post I made earlier on , and this error is causing from then onwards - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588659/using-viewer-page-to-switch-between-two-fragments-however-it-disappears-after

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/28556592/3678308

Answer (score 0):

It was the layout I was replacing, I was replacing the wrong one.